# Gradle resolve dependecies and build/run fine but IntelliJ do not

Tags: java, grails, intellij-idea, gradle, dependencies

I am using IntelliJ for one of my java projects. It has to build with gradle and from the command line, it works fine, both build and run. However, Intellij is not able to build and run the project.
It can import the project with all the dependencies, but it gives me this error:

```
Unable to save plugin settings: The plugin org.jetbrains.plugins.gradle failed to save settings and has been disabled. Please restart IntelliJ IDEA
```

I have already tried all the solution on the web:

- removing cache
- restart
- enable gradle
- enable grail
- reinstall intellij

The problem in the project is that when I am writing the java code the parser resolves all the classes, however, at the moment of build I get 92 error of this type:

```
Error:(5, 32) java: package org.eclipse.jdt.core.dom does not exist
```

But the external libraries are resolved and installed by gradle.
Any other solution?

Comment: See if https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/nextversion/ works. If not, report a bug at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA.

Comment: One thing that I have missed is that on another computer IntelliJ works fine. @CrazyCoder

Comment: Delete IDE folders and .gradle directory to start over: https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/articles/206544519.

Comment: This works but only the first time, if I close intelliJ and reopen it it produce the same errors @CrazyCoder

Comment: I figure out that IntelliJ is not able to delete file in project, it throws an JavaioException. And maybe could be the reason why it cannot rewrite setting.

Comment: Have you tried to used `local gradle distribution` + `offline work`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by jetBrains support, the problem was related to some missing permission as the project was contained in OneDrive with placeholder function active.
Moving the project outside the OneDrive directory will resolve the problem for now.